# Disable and enable video when div is toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with youtube's iframe (It can be any media site's iframe. youtube is just an example) in it. I need to show it or hide it on a button click.

I can easily toggle div's visibility but the video inside the div keeps playing. What i really need to do is to remove the div's content completely and re-insert the div's content instead of simple changing display css property.

This is my html setup.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="ytContainer">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wbkrlHDKvgE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <button id="toggle">Show/Hide Video</button>
</div>
```

My jQuery code so far -

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
      $("#ytContainer").toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

[jQuery detach](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR5-KmtL7MAhWWB44KHRj7DkwQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fdetach%2F&usg=AFQjCNEZMNWX9PLLOETrKA7TCGNwpZhI_A&sig2=g2lVoynvEOF1qSxrY02CcA) looks like the function that can work here, but so far i have not been able to make it work.

So, my question is: How can i completely remove a div's content and re-insert it back on command using jQuery ?

[jsFiddle for testing](https://jsfiddle.net/g5oaze9d/)

EDIT: 
I ended up with the following code. Used data- attribute to store the html content when i want to remove the html and re-insert it when demanded.

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
  var content = $(this).attr("data-content");
  if(content){
    $("#ytContainer").html(content);
    $(this).attr("data-content","");
  }else{
    content = $("#ytContainer").html();
    $(this).attr("data-content",content);
    $("#ytContainer").html("");
  }     
});
```

Any better solutions than this ?

Comment: I would think more on the approach of using Youtube API to play / pause the video.

Comment: @Burimi It can be iframe video of any site. Heck, it may even be soundcloud audio iframe.

Comment: Instead of `.attr()`, use `.data()` to store the HTML

Comment: @Koder >Any better solutions than this ?< Yes, see my answer.

Comment: @zer00ne Your solution is not better. Please see my earlier comment about how it can be any iframe video/audio src.

Comment: My bad, you don't full control of player? Just removing the iframe? You need to edit your title.